# What is causing these strange results in the Layer Symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, fields-attributes

I am using Arc 10.3.1 and I have a feature class with various INT fields that hold values for number of defect type found in this polygon.  Here is an example of my table:

[image]

Now when I go to the symbology options in my properties and I choose Unique Values, and hit add all values,  it adds the values for the proper field in the first section, but the second and third parts I don't know where this data is coming from.   IE in the map below the first blue symbol should just be 0 , and not 0,0,0  the third symbol should be green and be 1 , not 1, 3636, 3636.

[image]

Why am I seeing the broken window, none, none, when I am choosing unique values, so I should only being seeing the value from the field I want.  What could be causing this and is there a solution?

Comment: That is a very strange issue for sure. I just tried to re-create it and had no success in finding the same error. I did notice it is pulling in a field called "None" in your screenshot. It is almost reacting as a Unique Values, Many Fields instead of just Unique Values. anyways. I would close the map and create a new fresh MXD...if that doesn't work then I am interested in what others offer up as this is a strange one.

Answer (score 1):

@MDHald  very good catch, your finding of that None field is the answer!  there is a field called NONE,  and it appears when the Symbology is using Catagories Unique Values, it seems to grab the Value Field you specify, and then it grabs none, and none, which should be actually NOTHING.  But since I had a field named None, it was grabbing the values from that field and populating the last two value fields, even though I only told it to use a single value field.   Seems like maybe a bug in ESRI, so just dont name fields NONE!

[image]